# unpFlatView fails to display any data

Tags: teamstudio-unplugged

Xpage for Unplugged using the Unplugged mobile controls.  Page in question uses an unpFlatView control to display data.  Page works and displays expected view data when served up to a browser by the Domino server  (for what that's worth: I'm told that whether it works in a "real" browser is immaterial).

On my device (iPhone 4s, and any other device I emulate in Chrome via the device's "development server"), all I see is the view header block with the unpFlatView "title" value displayed, but no data rows.

The view in question uses @Today in the selection and in one of the columns, but I am assured that is OK. I have another view in the app that also uses @Today in selection, but not in any columns.  That view does sorta work in Unplugged: the rows appear but without the detail displayed: that's another issue where Unplugged differs to a browser.

I have tried ensuring that all the database data is transferred to the device. Makes no difference, except that the Sync & Index refresh process took 45 minutes.

I've checked and rechecked the view selection formula, noting that the view displays data in the Notes client and on an Xpage served by the domino server.  I removed a comment from the selection formula.  I simplified it - which won't do any harm.  While doing this, Iresynced the app on each change and inspected the results.  the one where I removed the comment, I got some of the data displayed - but it was missing the 1st 4 expected data rows Next change, back to no data at all being displayed and cannot reproduce the issue again.

I've also removed the @Today-dependant code in the 2nd column of the view: again, no impact.

Here's my Xpage content.

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:viewxmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:unp="http://unplugged.teamstudio.com">


    <xc:layout>
            <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:panelxp:key="facet_1">
                            <divid="contentwrapper">
                                    <unp:unpScrollableArea>
                                            <xp:this.facets>
                                                    <unp:unpFlatViewinsetData="true"
                                                            numberofrows="50"refreshmethod="pull"position="menu-aligned"
                                                            ajaxload="Yes"wrapsummarytext="no"enableAZPicker="no"
                                                            detailColumn="Where"summaryColumn="Name"title="Today"
                                                            viewName="Where are people TodayXP" xpageDoc="WeeklyLog.xsp"
                                                            xp:key="facet_1">
                                                    </unp:unpFlatView>
                                            </xp:this.facets>

                                    </unp:unpScrollableArea>
                            </div>
                    </xp:panel>
            </xp:this.facets>
    </xc:layout>
</xp:view>
```

Yes, I know you'll all say I should not use @Today in views, but the app actually works with it in the client (where it's always off a local replica) and in a regular server-served XPage.   Given what it does, doing anything else would be extremely convoluted, and for 35 records in the view, that would be pointless, too.

Comment: What are the column formulae of the "where" and "name" cols? I know the client reference implementation is no longer supported now that the "development server" feature has been introduced, but I still find it useful to see the actual view as it would be built on the device. So may be worth checking your view in that if you have a copy of it. I noticed a couple of errors in your XML e.g. <unp:unpFlatViewinsetData  but assume that's just a typo. Are there any errors in the Unplugged log?

Comment: The typo - that missing space - is from the copy/reformat/paste process.  the view columns are

Comment: Sorry about the "typos": they're from the copy/paste of the code.

Comment: The view columns are 1: @Name([CN]);WeeklyLogName)

Comment: Where (part 1) @If(@Weekday(@Today) = 2; WeeklyLogMondayWhere; @Weekday(@Today) = 3; WeeklyLogTuesdayWhere; @Weekday(@Today) = 4; WeeklyLogWednesdayWhere; @Weekday(@Today) = 5; WeeklyLogThursdayWhere; @Weekday(@Today) = 6; WeeklyLogFridayWhere; "") +

@If(@If(@Weekday(@Today) = 2; WeeklyLogMondayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 3; WeeklyLogTuesdayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 4; WeeklyLogWednesdayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 5; WeeklyLogThursdayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 6; WeeklyLogFridayNotes; "") = "";"";

Comment: part 2   
" - " + @If(@Weekday(@Today) = 2; WeeklyLogMondayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 3; WeeklyLogTuesdayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 4; WeeklyLogWednesdayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 5; WeeklyLogThursdayNotes; @Weekday(@Today) = 6; WeeklyLogFridayNotes; ""))  And there don't appear to be any errors in the Sync log. Can't see any device errors, either, tho I can't really see any debugging info on the device at all, nor can I get the debug toolbar to do anything helpful.

Comment: I've simplified that second column to remove the duplicated if statement: no impact.  Works when served by the Domino XPage server, doesn't work when served from the Unplugged server.

Comment: I agree with Martin: this must be about something in your that's not supported on Unplugged. There are 2 approaches you can take: strip down the view until its basics and then keep adding functionality until it breaks. Or create an `xp:repeat` to loop over the view entries. Inside the repeat you can add an `xp:text` to show the contents of the columns or write a message to the Debug Toolbar.

Comment: I can't see anything in your 2 columns that wouldn't work with Unplugged. Are there other cols in the view might contain functions that Unplugged doesn't support? As Mark says, strip it down to basics - or try a new view that only has the col(s) you need.

Comment: Those two columns are the only columns in the view!